# Needed advice for an enjoyable AI in Buraco card game

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, montecarlo

i’m trying to build an effective AI for the [Buraco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buraco) card game (2 and 4 players).

I want to avoid the heuristic approach : i’m not an expert of the game and for the last games i’ve developed this way i obtained mediocre results with that path.

I know the [montecarlo tree search algorithm](http://mcts.ai/about/index.html), i’ve used it for a checkers game with discrete result but I’m really confused by the recent success of other Machine Learning options.

For example i found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36366318/modelling-card-game-for-machine-learning) in stack overflow that really puzzles me, it says :
"So again: build a bot which can play against itself. One common basis is a function Q(S,a) which assigns to any game state and possible action of the player a value -- this is called Q-learning. And this function is often implemented as a neural network ... although I would think it does not need to be that sophisticated here.”

I’m very new to Machine Learning (this should be Reinforcement Learning, right?) and i only know a little of Q-learning but it sounds like a great idea: i take my bot, making play against itself and then it learns from its results… the problem is that i have no idea how to start! (and neither if this approach could be good or not).

Could you help me to get the right direction?
Is the Q-learning strategy a good one for my domain?
Is the Montecarlo still the best option for me?
Would it work well in a 4 players game like Buraco (2 opponents and 1 team mate)?
Is there any other method that i’m ignoring?

PS: My goal is to develop an enjoyable AI for a casual application, i can even consider the possibility to make the AI cheating for example by looking at the players hands or deck.  Even with this, ehm, permission i would not be able to build a good heuristic, i think :/

Thank you guys for your help!

Comment: Go for MCTS. Yeah, Reinforcement-learning is fun and can be powerful, but: it's much much harder to obtain sucess. Problems like autocorrelation when doing self-play really hurt. Additionally: you typically need to combine your RL-learned function-approximator with MCTS or AlphaBeta to be competetive (like used in AlphaGo). This is a lot of work and might even use tons of resources. AlphaGo for example was bootstrapped from historical games and learning by pure self-play is painful. Apart from that: Go is a deterministic game with full-information, while yours might not.If stochastic -> pain.

Comment: @sascha: MCTS is a particular variant within the theory of reinforcement learning, see e.g. chapter 8.7. of the current [Sutton and Barto draft](http://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/~straka/courses/npfl114/2016/sutton-bookdraft2016sep.pdf). RL does not automatically mean self-play.

Comment: @davidhigh Yes, ```MCTS ∈ RL```. But that does not collide with my comment, especially after the author talks about the non-use of approximate value-functions which i considered and mentioned in the RL-view, also used by AlphaGo.

Comment: @sascha: my comment was meant just as a ... comment :-). And yours is quite valuable, so thanks for that.

Comment: @Giggioz did you do any progress on this? I’d be interested in doing the same and I’m wondering how far did you get. Maybe we can work together.

Comment: Carlos, this post is 3 years old ;) MCTS was too slow and we ended up building a very complex euristich which works well but it's impossible to explain. Maybe in these 3 years some news approaches have been developed because the machine learning movement has improved a lot, but I can not help with this. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: thinking again about your knowledge in MCTS and your implementation of checkers, I think my answer is formulated too pedagogical -- you probably know much of this if you know MCTS. Nevertheless, I hope it helps. Feel free to ask specific questions in the comments.

---

I was the one to suggest you to open a new question, so I fell I should at least give an answer here. However, right at the beginning, I want to clarify about what should be expected here. The things you are asking for are quite complex and require some solid experience in the realization. I had the occasion to implement optimal strategies for quite a few games, and I'd consider this here still a heavy challenge. So I think the goal here is to get some overview -- and not a proper solution (which I couldn't give anyhow as I don't know the game of Buraco).

As stated in the other answer, the theory of reinforcement learning provides a solid foundation. A good introduction is the book of Sutton and Barto with the same title. It's really readible and I'd suggest to get through the first five chapters or so (these cover Dynamic Programming and Monte Carlo). Two points in which this book is not sufficient are: (i) it does not give explicit application to two-player games, and (ii) it mainly relies on tabular representations of the value functions (--no neural networks and the like are involved).

A elementary part of the implementation is the state `S` of the game. This state should capture the complete current status of the game as compact and non-redundant as possible. Further, for each state `S`, you need to be able to assign the available actions `A` (like taking a card). Moreover, depending on the method you want to apply, it helps to know the probability distribution `p(S'|S,A)` which gives the probability to end up in state `S'` when you are in state `S` and do action `A`. And finally, you need to specify the reward `r(S'|S,A)` when you are in state `S` and do the action `A` to end in `S'` (for two player zero-sum games the reward can be chosen quite easily: when `S'` is the state where you win, you get `+1` as reward, if you lose `-1`, otherwise `0` -- this however does not hold for games with more players or non-zero-sum games).

From a given state `S`, you further can derive the reduced states `S_P1`, `S_P2`, etc. which the single players see. Those states capture the information of a specific player (which is of course less than the complete state -- a player does not know the cards of the opponent, and also not the order of cards in the deck, for example). These reduced states provide the base on which players make their decisions. So, the goal for player 1 is to get a function `Q_1(S_P1, A)` which tells him: when I'm in state `S_P1`, I should at best do the action `A` (this is the idea of Q-learning). And the same holds for the other players. These functions have to be trained so that optimal results come out.

The way to do so is through the central equation of reinforcement learning, the Bellman equation. There are several solution methods like value iteration, Monte Carlo (this is basically the method you referenced in your link), temporal difference methods, and so on. Some of these methods can be interpreted as your digital players which repeatedly play against each other and in this process hopefully get better each. However, this is not guaranteed, it is easy to get stuck in local minima like in any optimization problem. At best you already have a good digital player at hand (from somewhere) and you train only one player to beat him -- in this way you reduce the two-player problem to a single-player problem which is much easier.

I'll make a cut here, because this stuff is really better to grasp from the book, and because I know this answer won't help you practically even if it were ten pages long. Here one last suggestion how to proceed: (i) get the foundations from the book, (ii) implement some toy problems therein, (iii) extend the stuff to two player games -- see also the minimax theorem for this, (iv) solve some more easy games (like tic-tac-toe, even this takes long), (v) get acquainted with neural networks and all this stuff, and (vi) tackle Buraco -- that's a tough program, however.

Comment: David, thank you so much for your effort here in this answer, i really appreciate it.

I spent the last two days getting as much as possibile about the topic of the machine learning to be able to navigate in all these terms and concept. I admit i am happy now to have a better understanding of your answer compared as just 2 days before :)
However your comment describes this approach as a daunting task, i'm just a beginner in the field of ML and this does not seem the best study case to start with.

I'm probably going for a different path, maybe a mix of heuristic and MCTS).

Comment: Thanks also for the book, i will check it for sure. 
I started my study path with those two courses : https://www.udemy.com/deeplearning/learn/v4/content and https://www.udemy.com/artificial-intelligence-az/learn/v4/content
and i have to say they are quite complete and well organized.